# Как придумать структуру самописного php движка

Tags: php, cms

Я хочу в сжатые сроки научиться проектировать удобные структуры самописных движков, без классов и переусложнений, чтобы их было легко модифицировать.

Путем слепых попыток, после освоения шаблонизации внезапно пришел к очень удобной для себя структуре. Проблема в том, что для редактирования какого-либо раздела приходится открывать 2 папки, и открывать 2 документа одинаковым именем - один шаблон, и один код, обрабатывающий этот шаблон.

Со временем начал мешать код и в шаблон, так реально быстрее.

Что можно почитать, чтобы быстро понять, какие структуры стоит делать, а какие нет, только без длинной философии, ато времени нет?

Comment: **"без классов и переусложнений, чтобы их было легко модифицировать"**, - если имелось в виду, необходим легко расширяемый движок, то как раз классы вам и нужны. Они должны быть достаточно абстрактны, ну и [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) в помощь

Comment: *Со временем начал мешать код и в шаблон, так реально быстрее.* — а теперь представьте, что этот же движок вам нужно будет использовать в другом проекте, либо вы захотите изменить дизайн проекта: что будет быстрее в этом случае, изменить один файл с месивом из кода и html, либо только шаблон? По теме — MVC, как пример

Comment: Без классов, обычными процедурами будет громоздко и не удобно, к тому-же, импорт переменных в функции будет производиться по средством `global` или прототип, что может раздуть и запутать код. Можете сделать динамичный класс с использованием магических методов и от него плясать.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению почитать про то, как обходиться без классов в современном PHP, как помещать код логики и разметки в один файл и как вообще идти вразрез с общепринятыми представлениями о хорошем коде, совершенно нечего. Это не значит, что ваша задумка обречена на провал, но быстро найти свой путь у вас не получится. Кроме того, со временем вы будете иметь дело не только со своими cms и фрэймворками и вам придётся-таки продираться через все эти классы и переусложнения.

Если вас интересует максимально быстрое освоение веб-разработки, то изучайте популярные фрэймворки (разобраться с ними гораздо проще, чем придумать и разработать свой "велосипед"). Если вы собираетесь обрести глубокое понимание основ программирования и веба, то продолжайте свои эксперименты в лабораторных условиях (без надежды на высокую зарплату и крупные проекты, по крайней мере до тех пор, пока вы не станете настоящим гуру).

Ну и небольшой пример без классов как пища для размышлений :-)

структура проекта:

```
.
├── actions
│   └── index.php
├── data
│   └── db.sq3
├── dependencies
│   ├── config.php
│   └── dbQuery.php
└── main.php
```

main.php:

```
<?php

$action = 'index.php';
require __DIR__ . '/actions/' . $action;

function appController($action, $getArgs) {
    static $getDependence;
    if ($getDependence === null) {
        $getDependence = initGetDependence(__DIR__ . '/dependencies');
    }

    $args = $getArgs($getDependence);
    try {
        $result = $action(...$args);
    } catch(Throwable $err) {
        throw new Exception('500');
    }

    return $result;
}

function initGetDependence($dir) {
    $getDependence = function($name) use($dir, &$getDependence) {
        $path = $dir . '/' . $name;
        $dependence = require $path;

        return $dependence($getDependence);
    };

    return $getDependence;
}
```

actions/index.php:

```
<?php

extract(appController(function($dbQuery) {
    list($rows) = $dbQuery('
        select *
        from `articles`
    ');

    return ['articles' => $rows];
}, function($getDependence) {
    return [
        $getDependence('dbQuery.php'),
    ];
}));

?>
<div>
    <?php foreach($articles as $article): ?>
        <div>
            <h2><?= htmlspecialchars($article['title']) ?></h2>
            <div>
                <?= $article['html'] ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

dependencies/dbQuery.php

```
<?php

return function($getDependence) {
    $config = $getDependence('config.php');
    $db = new PDO($config['db']);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // для примера
    $db->exec('drop table if exists `articles`');
    $db->exec('
        create table `articles` (
            `id` integer not null primary key autoincrement,
            `title` text,
            `html` text
        )
    ');
    $db->exec('delete from `articles`');
    $db->exec('
        insert into `articles` (`title`, `html`)
        values
            (
                \'Foo foo foo\',
                \'test <a href="/foo">FOO</a>\'
            ),
            (
                \'Bar bar bar\',
                \'test <a href="/bar">BAR</a>\'
            )
    ');

    return function($sql) use($db) {
        $st = $db->query($sql);

        return [
            $st->fetchAll(),
        ];
    };
};
```

dependencies/config.php:

```
<?php

return function() {
    return [
        'db' => 'sqlite:' . realpath(__DIR__ . '/../data/db.sq3'),
    ];
};
```

Наслаждайтесь `php -S localhost:8000 main.php`.